# Saving to their specific folders

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a inventory system for the patient or for the hospital,
im currently using xampp mysql as my database,
There are so many many patient so there are so many pictures to be uploaded 
 so here is my question,
**How can i connect or link automatically when the photo's been uploaded or how can i save to their specific folder that can find at my C:documents**

For example: THEY ALREADY HAVE THEIR SPECIFIC FOLDER

```
Patient: 3333333
Patient: 12312312
Patient: 555555
```

They Already have their specific folder im done with this*
im stuck right now at saving their image to their specific folder

Please click the image to understand clearly.
**The upload photo is the action to browse pictures and save** 
[image: HERES THE IMAGE]

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? If I understand correctly, you want to save images to a folder (on disk, each patient has their own unique folder) whenever a patient uploads them, but you want to check if the user already has a folder before saving.... right?

Comment: @BrendonDugan (Sir i already do the thing folder where their idnumber is the name of the folder this is done ) the problem is the save to their unique folders, and the patient cant upload, Only the staff can manage this upload, the picture is my actual interface of my websit sir thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a PHP file upload: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php  (see Example #2)

$uploaddir is the absolute path to the folder where the file is uploaded to; you might so something like this:

```
$userId = $user->getId();
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/userFolders/'.$userId.'/';
```

Also make sure the folders exist and your user has sufficient permissions to create files.